# How to copy only updated files/folders from aws s3 bucket to local machine?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, gzip

I have a requirement of copying certain files from an S3 bucket to local machine. Below are the important points to note on my requirement:

- The files are kept in S3 bucket based on the date folder.
- The files are in `csv.gz` extension and I need to change it to `csv` and copy it to my local machine.
- It keeps on updating every minute and I need to copy only the new files and process it. The processed files needs not to be copied again.

I have tried using sync folder but after processing of the file, the file name is renamed and again the csv.gz file is synced with the local folder.

I am planning to use some scheduled task to con.

Comment: As you have files in date folder, you can write a script say in Python and pull latest file from S3. You can process your file and change the extension in your script and save it.

Comment: But can I directly run the script on the aws s3 bucket files? I am not sure about this. Please help @ChandanKumar

Comment: Yes, you need to use boto3. Here is the document: https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/s3.html

Comment: You seems to be pretty new to AWS. I would suggest you to go through this [document](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/index.html) Go through the installation and configuration then start check S3 boto3 API, the link which i shared at first.

Answer (score 1):

Amazon S3 is a storage service. It cannot 'process' files for you.

If you wish to change the contents of a file (eg converting from `.csv.gz` to `.csv`), you would need to do this yourself on your local computer.

The [AWS Command-Line Interface (CLI)](http://aws.amazon.com/cli/) `aws s3 sync` command makes it easy to copy files that have been changed/added since the previous `sync`. However, if you are changing the files locally (unzipping), then you will likely need to write your own program to download from Amazon S3.

There are AWS SDKs available for popular programming languages. You can also do a web search to find sample code for using Amazon S3.